# What is going wrong with my wsgi setup?

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

I'm trying to setup uwsgi (and nginx eventually), but right now am stuck on uwsgi. I'm getting the following error when I try to run the server normally:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

And this is the output from running command uwsgi --http :8000 --module Hellfish.wsgi:

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.17 (64bit) on [Tue Jul  3 18:34:40 2018] ***
compiled with version: 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2) on 03 July 2018 20:44:01
os: Darwin-16.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0: Fri Apr 27 17:59:46 PDT 2018; root:xnu-3789.73.13~1/RELEASE_X86_64
nodename: Whodinis-MacBook-Pro.local
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 4
current working directory: /Users/whodini/Desktop/who/Web/Hellfish
detected binary path: /Users/whodini/Desktop/who/Web/Hellfish/env/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 709
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 256
lock engine: OSX spinlocks
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uWSGI http bound on :8000 fd 5
spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 70999)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:59020 (port auto-assigned) fd 4
Python version: 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5926, Jul 16 2017, 20:11:06)  [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x7fd92082c800
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 72888 bytes (71 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
base dir path
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./Hellfish/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 94, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_countries'
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 70998, cores: 1)
```

Not sure why it can't import module Django_countries. I'm kind of operating blind here because this is the first time I've done this and having trouble following docs and tutorials. I've tried to kill the port and restart it but came up with this issue again. Also not sure if my .ini file is in the right place or if its configured correctly. I put it in the same directory as my Hellfish.wsgi file. Hellfish is the name of my project. Finally, here is the contents of my .ini file:

```
[uwsgi]

socket = 127.0.0.1:8000

chdir = /Users/whodini/Desktop/who/Web/Hellfish/
home = /Users/whodini/Desktop/who/Web/Hellfish/env
module = Hellfish.wsgi:application
wsgi-file = Hellfish/wsgi.py
master = true
pidfile=/tmp/project-master.pid
vacuum=True
max-requests=5000

processes = 4
threads = 2
stats = 127.0.0.1:8000
```

Some help here would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you check if that package is installed? Try `pip freeze` on the command line to see if it is there. If not, try `pip install django_countries`. Also double check that you are using the same Python interpreter as `uwsgi` does using `pip --version`.

Comment: Yes Django_countries is installed in my virtual env. My pip version is 10.0.1. And in fact I just upgraded that in the middle of this process. What should I compare that to?

Comment: The output of `pip --version` should match the error message, i.e. `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/`

Comment: pip 10.0.1 from /Users/whodini/Desktop/who/Web/Hellfish/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6) - it looks matching. What do you think?

Comment: No, the paths don't match. Your pip command runs under the Hellfish virtualenv but uwsgi seems to be using the system wide Python 3.6 interpreter. Try adding `venv = /Users/whodini/Desktop/who/Web/Hellfish/env` to your `.ini` file.

Comment: Tried but no luck.

Comment: I think I should start over Selcuk. Before I break things further, is that as simple as uninstalling uwsgi, or is there a specific process I should go through to get back to the point where my development server was working and the site accessible? Thanks for your attempts to help me.

Comment: I wouldn't uninstall anything as it looks like this is a simple issue with your `.ini` file. I would suggest searching StackOverflow for similar issues and if that fails, re-wording and maybe reposting the question.